# Unity3D - Call Static method from Android

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I created simple plugin for opening Android Activity from Unity3D. Have problem to trigger method with parameters. Any ideas?

Java Code

```
 public static void Show(Activity activity, String value, String value2)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, DisplayAllUnits.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key1",value);
    myIntent.putExtra("key2",value2);
    activity.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

and in onCreate

```
   //load units for All Units placement from values
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       value = extras.getString("key1");
       value2 = extras.getString("key2");

    }
    a_id=value;
    p_id=value2;
```

C# code to trigger it:

```
 var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    var jo = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("secret.package;)but.it.s.correct");
    string value = "121";
    string value2 = "1400";
    jc.Call("Show", jo, "121", "1400");
```

And what is a problem:
-without parameters, works, with parameters I have following error:

```
I/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ldisplay/io/unity3dplugin/DisplayAllUnits;.Show(Lcom.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V"
                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ldisplay/io/unity3dplugin/DisplayAllUnits;.Show(Lcom.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `Call`, which is meant to call an instance method. You want [`CallStatic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic.html), which calls a static method.

Comment: You solved my problem ;) I just started to learn Unity3D, thank you. Ill accept answer in 4 minutes